# AndroidGuiExample failed compiling

Tags: android, gcc, android-ndk, openframeworks

I'm trying to get acquainted with openFrameworks and Android application. I installed both Android SDK and NDK (r10e) and I tried to compile the AndroidGuiExample. 
Unfortunately, this is what the terminal returned at the end:

```
undefined reference to 'std::__throw_out_of_range_fmt(char const*, ...)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [libs/armeabi-v7a/libOFAndroidApp.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Debug] Error 2
make: *** [AndroidDebug] Error 2
```

I have not sincerely a clear idea of what happened.
Anyone could help me in understanding the error and finding a solution?
Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you configured NDK ?

---

With a text editor, edit the file

```
libs/openFrameworksCompiled/project/android/paths.make
```

and set the NDK path to the correct folder:

```
NDK_ROOT=/path/to/the/ndk
```

So it looks like this

```
NDK_ROOT=/Developer/android-ndk-r10e
```

happy coding ! :)